# How to set a scroll limit when using Android-Week-View

Tags: android, android-library

The awesome library Android-Week-View https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View provides infinite horizontal scroll further or backwards the days of a calendar. And also vertical scroll over the hours of a day.

However, let´s say I wanna limit the scroll only over 6 months further or back to the current date and only the times between 18:00 and 23:00. Is it currently possible to define these kinds of range limit?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setXScrollingSpeed` from the library. I dont think it is possible to set min date and max date with this library.